# C File Handling - Trouble using Strings with Char

Tags: c++

Good day, I'm having some trouble with my code. I just started with file handling last week and I'm currently stuck with adding Strings to the program. I would like to add the names in the main program from the file, but I've tried pretty much everything. Any help would be highly appreciated. Also, this is my first time on Stack Overflow, so sorry if I missed posting any information.

The picture includes the Input.txt file as well as the current output. I added console output to test the problem and it seems to have something to do with the characters. I've tried using String itself, but that was still a fail. Also, I'm not allowed to use the C++ way of file handling (if that makes sense). [I am allowed to use C++ though] - Doing this whole program for practice for my upcoming exams.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int ReadFile(char*,int*,double*);

int main()
{
    char names[128];
    int ages[128];
    double salaries[128];

    int size = ReadFile(names, ages, salaries);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("My name is %s, and I am %d years old. My salary is $%.2lf\n", *(names+i), *(ages+i), *(salaries+i));
    }

    return 0;
}

int ReadFile(char *namesArr, int *ageArr, double *salaryArr)
{
    FILE *IN = fopen("Input.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    if(IN == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error! Can't open file.";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        char name[20];
        int age = 0;
        double salary = 0.00;
        while(fscanf(IN, " %c,%d,%lf", &name, &age, &salary) != EOF)
        {
            *(namesArr + i) = *name;
            *(ageArr + i) = age;
            *(salaryArr + i) = salary;
            cout << *(namesArr+i) << " ";
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(IN);
    return i;
}
```

**Input.txt:**

> Kazu,21,2250.00
>  Anonymous,34,3500.25
>  John,31,2750.00 
> Paul,25,3125.25
>
> Jin,19,1750.00

Comment: If the target of your `fscanf` is a string, you need to use `%s` format specifier. `%c` expects single characters. `C0000005` error, in Windows, appears when there's some issues with memory, in your case probably related to the attempt to print unterminated strings. PS: `using` and `cout` mean you are actually using C++ instead of pure C.

Comment: Your question has stuff like `cout`, `#include <string>` and `using namespace std` that makes it not a C program. Either edit your post to make it a valid C program or replace your c tag with a c++ one.

Comment: Sorry for not including C++ tag. I'm allowed to use C++, but I need to use the C way of file handling. I have changed the %c to %s, but it only prints the first character of the names. It also does not print in the main program as shown in the image.

Comment: Replace `*(x + y) ` with the equivalent but more readable `x[y]`.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text. Program output is text.

Comment: Please, don't confuse `#include <string>` with `#include <string.h>`. `#include <string>` is about `class std::string;`, but `#include <string.h>` is about the [C standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). These are two complete separate things (except both are about handling character sequences in general). I didn't see any occurrence of `std::string` in your code. So, please, drop `#include <string>`. It's needless and, at best, confusing.

Comment: The only specific C++ code I found in your exposed code, are the few usages of `cout <<` which could be easily replaced by `printf()`s. So, with least effort, this could be turned into a clean C source without the necessity to mix C and C++ (which I consider at best as a source of uncertainty but not as a contribution of any added value).

Comment: Tip: compare against the value wanted, not against one of the many unwanted values. `fscanf(IN, " %c,%d,%lf", &name, &age, &salary) != EOF` --> `fscanf(IN, " %c,%d,%lf", &name, &age, &salary) == 3`.

Comment: Mixing `printf()` output with `cout <<` leads to trouble.  Choose one.

Comment: Since you are using C++ you should be using iostream. stdio.h is a brittle dangerous crap library and if you have the option to avoid it you should do so.

Comment: Ruan Meyer,  a `char` cannot store "Anonymous".  What is the longest name allowed?  May a name have spaces (or ' or - or etc.) in it like `"Betty Jo Smith-O'Byrn"`?

Comment: Names are [tricky](https://xkcd.com/327/). 

Answer (score 0):

Save time, enable all compiler warnings

`My name is %s` --> `My name is %c`

---

If you want to read in the name, and not just the first letter, many more changes needed too such as:

```
    char name[20];
    int age = 0;
    double salary = 0.00;
    while(fscanf(IN, " %19[A-Za-z'] ,%d ,%lf", &name, &age, &salary) == 3)
    {
        *(namesArr + i) = *name; // This only copies the first `char`
        strcpy(TBD, name); // Need something like this.
                           // TBD is a pointer to an `char` array
        *(ageArr + i) = age;
        *(salaryArr + i) = salary;
        cout << TBD << " ";
        i++;
    }
```